# Profile-dependent log4j2 configuration with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j2

I am trying to use log4j2 in a Spring boot application with Gradle. I have 4 different profiles: `it, dev, mac, was`. Correspondingly, I have 4 different log4j2 config files: `log4j2-it.xml, log4j2-dev.xml, log4j2-mac.xml, log4j2-was.xml`. Based on the selected profile, I want to pick the correct log4j2 configuration file so that it is configured accordingly.

First off, to get log4j2 to even work, I excluded
`spring-boot-starter-logging` and included instead
`spring-boot-starter-log4j2`. Before doing this log4j2 did not work at all.

I’ve looked into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559824/spring-profiles-different-log4j2-configs), but I could not get the accepted answer to work. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30376025/6575658), setting the
`logging.config` property won’t work. Furthermore, my project does not have a start script, so I cannot pass the argument with the `-D` flag.

I have been able to select one of the configuration files by adding a
`log4j2.component.properties` file and specifying the config file to use there ([see here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location)), however I haven’t found a way to make this profile-dependent.

Also if I have a file named just `log4j2.xml`, this is discovered and loaded as expected.

After doing a lot of searching, I’ve seen a bunch of solutions for logback and given them a try to see if any would work with log4j2, but unsurprisingly none of these were successful.

Is there a way for me to accomplish this? For example, when running tests the `it` profile is selected and the `log4j2-it.xml` file should be used to configure logging. Perhaps there’s something I’ve missed, as I would expect that profile-specific log4j2 configuration should be possible, but thus far I have not found anything that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a `@Component` with a `@PostConstruct` method wherein I did

```
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
context.setConfigLocation(URI.create("path to file"));
context.reconfigure();
```

Thanks to alan7678's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31191643/6575658).